# UIButton not calling selector

Tags: objective-c, user-interface, uiview, uibutton

I'm creating a `UIButton` programmatically, but when I tap the button it does not call the selector at all. The button is created in the following method:

```
- (UIButton*) createNewsButtonFromItem: (MWFeedItem*) item origin: (CGPoint) origin color: (UIColor*) color
{
    UIButton* titleButton = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];

    titleButton.frame = CGRectMake(origin.x, origin.y, CGRectGetWidth(self.mainScrollView.frame), CGRectGetHeight(self.mainScrollView.frame));

    int size;
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        size = IPAD_TEXT_SIZE;
    }
    else
    {
        size = IPHONE_TEXT_SIZE;
    }
    titleButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName: @"STHeitiTC-Medium" size: size];
    titleButton.titleLabel.minimumScaleFactor = .5;
    titleButton.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [titleButton setTitleColor: color forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    [titleButton setTitle: item.title forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    [titleButton addTarget: self action: @selector(openInWebView) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [titleButton.titleLabel setNumberOfLines: 0 ];
    [titleButton.titleLabel sizeToFit];

    titleButton.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    return titleButton;
}
```

Which is being called in a method to create a view:

```
- (UIView*) viewForItem: (MWFeedItem*) item
{
    // figure out if it should be veritical
    BOOL heads = arc4random() % 2;
    BOOL tails = arc4random() % 2;
    CGPoint origin = self.mainScrollView.contentOffset;
    CGSize size = self.mainScrollView.bounds.size;

    // define the four possible points
    CGPoint left = CGPointMake(origin.x - size.width, origin.y);
    CGPoint right = CGPointMake(origin.x + size.width, origin.y);
    CGPoint top = CGPointMake(origin.x, origin.y - size.height);
    CGPoint bottom = CGPointMake(origin.x, origin.y + size.height);

    // set up frames 
    BOOL sideways = heads;
    CGPoint point1 = sideways ? (tails ? left : right) : (tails ? top : bottom);
    CGPoint point2 = sideways ? (tails ? right : left) : (tails ? bottom : top);
    UIColor* color = isBlack ? [UIColor blackColor] : [UIColor whiteColor];
    UIColor* otherColor = isBlack ? [UIColor whiteColor] : [UIColor blackColor];

    UIButton* titleButton = [self createNewsButtonFromItem: item origin: point1 color: color];
    UIView* background = [self createBackgroundViewOrigin: point2 color: otherColor];

    UIView* container = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: self.mainScrollView.bounds];

    [container addSubview: background];
    [container addSubview: titleButton];

    return container;

}
```

I'm using the above method to create a view and place it in my main container view:

```
UIView* view = [self viewForItem: item];
[self.mainScrollView addSubview: view];    
[self animateIntoPlace: view];
```

And then animating it into the center of the frame:

```
- (void) animateIntoPlace: (UIView*) view
{
    // find out frame of current view
    CGPoint origin = self.mainScrollView.contentOffset;
    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(origin.x + CGRectGetWidth(self.mainScrollView.frame) / 2, origin.y + (CGRectGetHeight(self.mainScrollView.frame) / 2));

    for (UIView* subview in view.subviews)
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration: .3 animations:^{
            subview.center = center;
        }];
    }
}
```

When the button is tapped it's supposed to call the following method, but never hits it:

```
- (void) openInWebView
{
    UIViewController* container = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

    // create webview
    UIWebView* webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame: container.view.frame];
    webView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

    // load webview with URL
    NSString* link = ((MWFeedItem*)[self.mainQueue objectAtIndex: currentIndex]).link;
    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString: link];
    NSURLRequest* request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: url];
    [webView loadRequest: request];

    // close button
    UIButton* closeButton = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [closeButton setTitle: @"X" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    [closeButton addTarget: self action: @selector(closeWebView) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    closeButton.frame = CGRectMake(5, 5, 30, 30);

    // add views to the container
    [container.view addSubview: webView];
    [container.view addSubview: closeButton];

    [self presentViewController: container animated: YES completion:^{
        shouldCycle = NO;
    }];

}
```

Does anyone see what's wrong with this? I've done this a million times before and can't pick out why it's just not working. A button shouldn't take this long to make >_<

Comment: does the button color change as if it has been pressed. in other words are you sure another view is not blocking it?

Comment: @JustinMeiners No it doesn't, good call. I'll check the subview stack in the debugger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably forgot to set view's `userInteractionEnabled = YES`
In your case:

```
UIView* view = [self viewForItem: item];
view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Comment: Wasn't this view, but I had to enable user interaction on the `UIScrollView` container